# My old $interval is not stopping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intervals

I am trying to implement Auto Save , saving the values written in a textarea every 30 seconds , i have put ng-change in my html with debounce value of 1 second . 
So whatever i write goes to controller after debounce time of 1 second.

Inside my controller function i have written to call a interval like :

```
interval = $interval(autoSaveInterval, 
parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("autoSaveFrequency")), '', '', [comment, id, 
moduleName]);
```

Inside AutoSaveIntervalFunction i am calling one more function to save the data to server .

and then i cancelling the above Interval by

```
$interval.cancel(interval);
```

but what i noticed is : 
Suppose if i write 'My Name' i take a gap of 2 seconds after writing 'My' text 'My ' goes to AutoSaveInterval Function . then 'My Name' goes after 2 seconds . 
But i noticed that old interval having the value 'My' has not got destroyed yet .

How can i fix this . please help . 
As my text 'My Name' is being overwritten by 'My' text .

Comment: What creates the interval? Is it the handler (the one that fires after the debounce)?

Comment: After writing anything in textarea after 1 second it goes to a function inside whic i have written

       interval = $interval(autoSaveInterval, 
      parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("autoSaveFrequency")), '', '', 
      [comment, id, 
     moduleName]);

calling  'AutoSaveInterval'  Function every30 seconds my Auto Save frequency is 30 seconds . stored in session

Comment: I think best for now is to check if `interval` already exists (not null/undefined) before creating a new one, skipping creating one if it already exists. When the timer fires, set it to null/undefined. This should prevent creating multiple timers.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply . I doing the same .